# facebook integration with libgdx on android

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx

I am integrating `FaceBook` with `Libgdx`. Some of the `FaceBook` methods require a context (from the `Android Activity`). I have found some resources to help me with [this](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup)

After I followed this tutorial I had my `Interface`, I then created an object that implemented that `Interface`. (this object contained the `Context`) and passed that object into the initialize method in the `MainActivity` of my Android project. The problem is I cannot access the context in my main `libgdx` project as it cannot access the android libraries `android.content.Context`.

Please help me resolve this issue as it is necessary to have `FaceBook` login with my app.

I have already looked through a massive amount of questions on this and not one has a definitive answer. Thanks in advance.

//EDIT

After attempting Vikalp's solution I nearly have it working. I know my facebook code works as I have tested it with native android.

SO the new solution is: Created an interface in LIBGDX(Maininterface), created a facebookCallBack interface in LIBGDX to receive callback info from MainInterface. 
Created a class which creates the MainInterface and contains all my facebook code(which works as expected on native android). I create an instance of this class and pass it through to LIBGDX where I can receive callbacks in facebookCallBack, from MainInterface.

Im getting a null error in the logcat about the applicaitonID, however it is the same set up as my native android project so it should find the id in the meta data of the manifest.

The logcat output is printed below:

```
07-09 10:31:57.660: D/dalvikvm(7261): GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 7% free 12371K/13191K,              paused 3ms+12ms, total 34ms
07-09 10:32:00.200: I/System.out(7261): clicked!
07-09 10:32:00.210: W/dalvikvm(7261): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature    (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
07-09 10:32:00.210: W/dalvikvm(7261): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
07-09 10:32:00.210: I/dalvikvm(7261): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
07-09 10:32:00.210: W/dalvikvm(7261): VFY: unable to resolve static method 304: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
07-09 10:32:00.210: D/dalvikvm(7261): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
07-09 10:32:00.295: W/dalvikvm(7261): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d422a0)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2837
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:86)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(Utility.java:166)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:221)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:213)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.facebook.Session$Builder.build(Session.java:1454)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:863)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:805)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.FB.GDX.FBActivity$1.getResultFromFaceBook(FBActivity.java:66)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.FB.GDX.GDXScreen$1.clicked(GDXScreen.java:123)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:82)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:57)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:334)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:359)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:486)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
07-09 10:32:00.300: E/AndroidRuntime(7261):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
07-09 10:32:04.060: D/dalvikvm(7261): GC_CONCURRENT freed 356K, 8% free 12449K/13447K,             paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
```

//EDIT 2

On the android side, I have an activity that creates the MainInterface as I need an activity to start a Session. The code of that class is below:

```
public class FBActivity extends Activity {


private Activity thisActivity = this;
private MainInterface object;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}
   //methods
    public MainInterface getMaininterface()
    {
        if(object==null)
        {
            //create MainInterface object for facebook callbacks
            object = new MainInterface(){

                CallBackInterface fbCallbacks;

                private String TAG = "MainActivity";

                public Session.StatusCallback callback;



                public void registerCallBackInterFace(CallBackInterface callBacks){

                    this.fbCallbacks = callBacks;

                }

                public Session.StatusCallback getCallback()
                {
                    return this.callback;
                }

                public void getResultFromFaceBook(){
                    /* write your code for faceBook here */


                    Session.openActiveSession(thisActivity,true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                            if (state.isOpened()) { //note: I think session.isOpened() is the same

                            fbCallbacks.setLoggedIn(true);

                                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());

                                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,

                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {


                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            if (user != null) {

                                            email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();

                                            Log.i(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());

                                            Log.i(TAG, "Email " + user.asMap().get("email"));




                                        }
                                    }

                                });

                            } else if (state.isClosed()) {



                                fbCallbacks.setLoggedIn(false);
                            }


                        }




                    });
                    System.out.println("main interface created");


                }


                };}
        return object;
    }
    @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

The getResultFromFaceBook() method gets called when a button in LIBGDX is pressed.

//EDIT 3

The AppID is referenced in the manifest like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

and the value of the ID is stored in strings.xml as such:

```
<string name="app_id">**************</string>
```

The packageManager may be giving the null error but I'm not sure.

Comment: please provide code how you are using application id in your code

Comment: I have updated my question with code, I believe it coule be when I create a session with "Session.openActiveSession(thisActivity,true, new Session.StatusCallback() {..", but I'm really not sure, I have tested the same code on a core android project and it works flawlessy..Thanks for any help/advice

Comment: I think the way you have provided the application id may not be working for you. Or you might have used the wrong tag for using application id. please provide the line how you are using application id in your code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by where I use it? it's included in the manifest as meta data, and it's stored as a string value in the gdx res/values/strings.xml , I have edited my code to show how they are referenced. I think when you open a session, if an appId has not been given it looks for it in the manifest, I have not explicitly used the appID, so it should be working, however in the logcat I'm not sure if its the appID or the packageManager(android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:86)) that is giving the null error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is implement your Facebook Library in android project and call all the methods of that library from the interface that you have created. Let say your interace is named MainInterface

For getting the result from android side to your main project you can create another interface say CallBackInterFace as well as its implementing class in main project and register this interface with your android project and get callbacks from there..

eg.
In Main Project you can create interface as

```
public interface MainInterFace{

    public interface CallBackInterface{
         public void getInt(int output);
    }

    public void registerCallBackInterFace(CallBackInterface callBacks);

    public void getResultFromFaceBook();
}
```

Create a Implementing callBack Class in main project as:

```
class FaceBookCallBacks implements CallBackInterFace{
   public void getInt(int output){
       System.out.println(output);
   }
}
```

register object of this class with android project by calling

```
.....
registerCallBackInterFace(new FaceBookCallBacks());
....
```

On android side what you can do is

create an object implementing that interface as

```
...

MainInterFace object = new MainInterFace(){

       CallBackInterface callback;

       public void registerCallBackInterFace(CallBackInterface callBacks){
            this.callback = callbacks;
       }

       public void getResultFromFaceBook(){
           /* write your code for faceBook here */
           int result = 10;    //eg for returning a value
           callback.getInt(result);
       }
};
...
```

This can help you with both your ios and Gwt Projects

**You can even visit this Link to check for solution   https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific**

Comment: Hey Vikalp, I have attempted your solution and nearly have it working, I have edited my answer to show a problem, hopefully you can help me resolve it, thanks for the response.

Comment: I have added a second EDIT to my answer, Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, a solution would be:

-Create a project (i.e. FacebookImpl) which implements your Facebook tasks. You can implement the Interface and your concrete class there.  So, this project depends on Facebook SDK.

-Include that project in your LibGDX Core project and make your calls through the "FacebookImpl". Therefore, from your MainActivity, you can supply your Context to the "FacebookImpl" and your LibGDX core project will make the calls without knowing anything about Android classes.

-Lastly, your "FacebookImpl" should have one instance. You should initialize it once in your MainActivity and the core project should use the same instance.

Hope it helps, even though it has been some time since you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have attempted Vikalp's solution however I am getting an error, hopefully you can help me resolve this. Cheers

Comment: getResultFromFacebook() method is defined at core project? And what happens in that method? As in, if you are directly trying to open a new session from the core project, I think it won't be able to find the appid. However, if you are trying to open a new session via your interface ( defined at Android project), I am not sure what is happening. Supplying some code might help.

Comment: I have added a second EDIT to my answer, Cheers.

Comment: Yes, facebook SDK uses appID implicitly -reading it from the manifest- if you do not provide it when you open a session, so that part is OK. I think best you can do is an in depth debugging, and I would take a look at which method gets called from which thread.

Comment: Ah thanks, erm I will re-look over everything. In the logcat I'm not sure if its the appID or the packageManager(android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.j‌​ava:86)) that is giving the null error, Which is confusing and makes my think my Activity set up is wrong when I open the session :/

Answer (score 0):

I have similar setup and it works. According to your error log, seems the android support library is missing:

```
Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
```

You can include the android-support-v4.jar from facebookSDK's libs folder. Make sure this jar file is exporting in the Android project's Java Build Path and pushed to the top of list.